# Specifying styles for portions of a PyYAML dump

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I'm using YAML for a computer and human-editable and readable input format for a simulator. For human readability, some parts of the input are mostly amenable to block style, while flow style suits others better.

The default for PyYAML is to use block style wherever there are nested maps or sequences, and flow style everywhere else. *default_flow_style* allows one to choose all-flow-style or all-block-style.

But I'd like to output files more of the form

```yaml
bonds:
- { strength: 2.0 }
- ...
tiles:
- { color: red, edges: [1, 0, 0, 1], stoic: 0.1}
- ...
args: 
    block: 2
    Gse: 9.4
```

As can be seen, this doesn't follow a consistent pattern for styles throughout, and instead changes depending upon the part of the file. Essentially, I'd like to be able to specify that all values in some block style sequences be in flow style. Is there some way to get that sort of fine-level control over dumping? Being able to dump the top-level mapping in a particular order while not requiring that order (eg, omap) would be nice as well for readability.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out this can be done by defining subclasses with representers for each item I want not to follow default_flow_style, and then converting everything necessary to those before dumping. In this case, that means I get something like:

```python
class blockseq( dict ): pass
def blockseq_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data, flow_style=False )

class flowmap( dict ): pass
def flowmap_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data, flow_style=True )

yaml.add_representer(blockseq, blockseq_rep)
yaml.add_representer(flowmap, flowmap_rep)

def dump( st ):
    st['tiles'] = [ flowmap(x) for x in st['tiles'] ]
    st['bonds'] = [ flowmap(x) for x in st['bonds'] ]
    if 'xgrowargs' in st.keys(): st['xgrowargs'] = blockseq(st['xgrowargs'])
    return yaml.dump(st)
```

Annoyingly, the easier-to-use dumper.represent_list and dumper.represent_dict don't allow flow_style to be specified, so I have to specify the tag, but the system does work.

Comment: Is your comment still up-to-date about `dumper.represent_sequence` and `dumper.represent_dict` not having an option flow_style? see http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dumper

Comment: Actually I try to apply your `flowmap` on a sequence: ` - edges:\n - [1,2]\n - [2, 1, [1, 0]]`. I'd like to have every edge on single separate line (as denoted by `\n`). Currently, it looks like this: ` - edges:\n - [1,2] \n  - 1\n - 2\n - [1, 0]`

Comment: Yes, my comment is still valid; `represent_mapping` has it, but the other two don't; they're probably just wrappers for `represent_mapping`. As for what you're doing, flowmap is not what you want. You a sequence (under edges:) that you want to have flow_style=True, not a mapping.

Comment: Can you have a look into my posted [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974357/specifying-styles-for-portions-of-a-pyyaml-dump-ii-sequences). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example for @cge's answer (unfortunately, it took some efforts to run the his example) with slightly modifications:

```py
import yaml

class noflow_dict(dict):
    pass

def noflow_dict_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:map", data, flow_style=False)

class flow_dict(dict):
    pass

def flow_dict_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:map", data, flow_style=True)

yaml.add_representer(noflow_dict, noflow_dict_rep)
yaml.add_representer(flow_dict, flow_dict_rep)

def dump(st):
    st["flow"] = [flow_dict(x) for x in st["flow"]]
    st["noflow"] = [noflow_dict(x) for x in st["noflow"]]
    return yaml.dump(st)

obj = {
    "flow": [
        {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        {"d": 4, "e": 5},
    ],
    "noflow": [
        {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
        {"D": 4, "E": 5},
    ],
}
print(dump(obj))
```

Output is

```yaml
flow:
- {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
- {d: 4, e: 5}
noflow:
- A: 1
  B: 2
  C: 3
- D: 4
  E: 5
```

All credits are to [@cge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14001707/3364871).