# Specifying styles for portions of a PyYAML dump (II): sequences

Tags: python, formatting, yaml

This is a follow up question to [Specifying styles for portions of a PyYAML dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000893/specifying-styles-for-portions-of-a-pyyaml-dump/):

Consider following code contaning as input manually formatted YAML data. I am modifying the YAML data, but would like to keep edges on single lines in the written YAML file.

```
import yaml

st2 = yaml.load("""
edges:
- [1, 2]
- [2, 1, [1,0]]
""")
print yaml.dump(st2)

class blockseq( dict ): pass
def blockseq_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', data, flow_style=False )

class flowmap( dict ): pass
def flowmap_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data, flow_style=True )

class blockseqtrue( dict ): pass
def blockseqtrue_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_mapping( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', data, flow_style=True )

yaml.add_representer(blockseq, blockseq_rep)
yaml.add_representer(blockseqtrue, blockseqtrue_rep)
yaml.add_representer(flowmap, flowmap_rep)

st2['edges'] = [ blockseqtrue(x) for x in st2['edges'] ]
print yaml.dump(st2)
```

This script exits with following output showing an error:

```
edges:
- [1, 2]
- - 2
  - 1
  - [1, 0]  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-yaml-rep.py", line 42, in <module>
    st2['edges'] = [ blockseqtrue(x) for x in st2['edges'] ]
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the two classes I had both operate on dicts, not lists. You want something that will work with lists:

```
class blockseqtrue( list ): pass
def blockseqtrue_rep(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_sequence( u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', data, flow_style=True )
```

Python lists are YAML sequences / seqs. Python dicts are YAML mappings/maps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing round-trip YAML in python it is much more easy to use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (I am the author of that enhanced version of PyYAML).
It preserves flow/block style sequences/lists and mapppings/dicts (as well as comments):

```
import ruamel.yaml

st2 = ruamel.yaml.load("""
edges:
- [1, 2]    # <- change the second item
- [2, 1, [1,0]]
""", Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)

st2['edges'][0][1] = 42
print(ruamel.yaml.dump(st2, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper))
```

will give you:

```
edges:
- [1, 42]   # <- change the second item
- [2, 1, [1, 0]]
```

As you can see this preserves the block style on the topmost sequence (the value of `edges`) and flow style on the other sequences.